# how to make r read files from directories containing non-English characters

Tags: r, path, character, non-english

There are two folders on my desktop and they include the same files. It seems, directories (paths) containing non-English characters don't work in my current windows environment.

```
> setwd("C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder_name_including_only_english_characters")
> list.files()
[1] "test.csv"    "test.jpg"    "test.pdf"    "Test.R"      "test.sql"    "test.xlsx"
> setwd("C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder_name_including_non_english_characters_like_ıüö")
> list.files()
character(0)
```

I am not sure whether this is something related with the settings of R or windows 10.

I don't have such an issue with my other computer.

**UPDATE**:

During my recent tries, I have noticed that, although the list.files() function fails, R can still read files from the directories containing non-English characters using the built in read.csv2 function. However, when I tried to read xlsx files, for example:

```
openxlsx::read.xlsx(paste0("C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder_name_including_non_English_characters_like_ıüö","/test.xlsx"))
```

it gives the error below. (btw, openxlsx::read.xlsx() function reads the files from directories containing only English characters successfully.

```
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

I suspect the reason behind both the fail of the function list.files() and the error on using openxlsx::read.xlsx() function may be the same.

My question is: what setting(s) should I change to make R successfully recognize the directories containing non-English characters?

Comment: After `setwd`, do `getwd` to check if the working directory is currently set. If not, try to remove the the ticks from the non-English words.

Comment: it sets the working directory without any error message.  setwd("C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder_name_including_non_english_characters_like_ıüö")
> getwd()
"C:/Users/my_user/Desktop/folder_name_including_non_english_characters_like_ıüö"

Comment: Try to change your R session system language with `Sys.setlocale(locale = "your_language")`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; it is already set: Sys.getlocale() "LC_COLLATE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_CTYPE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_MONETARY=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Turkish_Turkey.1254" .  Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After banging my heads for hours, `Sys.glob(*.*)` is the only possible option when `list.files` fail.

```
> Sys.setlocale(locale = 'Turkish_Turkey.1254')
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_CTYPE=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_MONETARY=Turkish_Turkey.1254;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Turkish_Turkey.1254"
> setwd('C:/Users/SA31/non_english_characters_like_ıüö')
> list.files()
character(0)
> Sys.glob('*.*')
[1] "New Text Document.txt"
```

Updated code without `setwd`:

```
> Sys.glob('C:/Users/SA31/non_english_characters_like_ıüö/*')
[1] "C:/Users/SA31/non_english_characters_like_ıüö/New Text Document.txt"
[2] "C:/Users/SA31/non_english_characters_like_ıüö/New folder"
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine. I wonder if it is possible to use Sys.glob() by passing a directory into it that is different from predefined working directory. If not, that means there needs to be consecutive setwd() usage when we want to read data from different directories.

Comment: Please check the updated code, you can use `paste0` for building such a path

Comment: Would be great if you could let us know if it's the answer you expected!

Comment: Sure, I will try asap and let you know.

Comment: amrrs, thanks again for your effort on this. Your last suggestion is a nice workaround to print the files in these problematic directories. However, it seems I need a solution that fixes the necessary setting in my R or windows environment. Please see the update on the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the system locale for non-unicode programs to Turkish fixed the issue.
"All Control Panel Items" > "Region and Language" > "Admimistrative" > "Change System Locale"